# splitting a tar

Tags: tar, split

I was tossed into Linux at work and have no experience with it what so ever. The guy that's training me gives me little tasks to figure out as I go, and I'm stuck. Today he told me to tar a file and split it into smaller files. I figured that out pretty quick. Then he told me to tar a file and split it in one command. I'm using a GoPro file GOPR0005.MP4, and have managed to do it with:

```
tar -czvf - GOPR0005.MP4 | split -b 5M
```

but my outputs are xaa, xab, ect. How can I name my outputs to something like goproaa, goproab, ect...? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the prefix that way:

```
tar -czvf - GOPR0005.MP4 | split -b 5M - gopro
```

`-` is used to tell `split` to use `stdin` just like you use it to tell `tar` to use `stdout`.

Comment: I'm mad at myself now. I've tried to put the gopro everywhere in there, but I didn't use the -. This has been a many hour long issue. Thanks!